# Terraform: How to Deal with Optional Input Variable

Tags: terraform

So I came across this general problem and didn't find an answer yet.

Problem: The input value can have optional variables, like the case below, `group_memberships` is an optional input, at the moment I make it an empty string input for this to work.
But if I comment it out like shown below and run it, I would get the error:

```
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Basically it's complaining that I don't have `list_of_users.test_user.group_memberships`.Is there a way to tell terraform if the input is not declared, just ignore it? I know I can leave it the way it is but user can potentially have many optional values, and making lots of empty input doesn't really make sense.

Thanks! First post question, sorry about poor layout for the code : )

in my .tfvars file:

```
  list_of_users = {
  regular_user = {
    email = "pdv@abc.com",
    group_memberships = "regular_group"
  },
  test_user = {
    email = "test@abc.com",
//    group_memberships = ""    <------ Currently can work if not comment out, looking for solution that I can remove those reduent empty declariation
  },
  admin_user = {
    email = "admin@abc.com",
    group_memberships = "admin_group"
  }
}
```

in .tf file:

```
variable "list_of_users" {}
resource "user_api_from_provider" "user_generate" {
  for_each = var.list_of_users
    email = each.value["email"]
    group_memberships = each.value["group_memberships"] !=""? [user_api_from_provider.group_generate[each.value["group_memberships"]].id] : null
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform optional nested object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904745/terraform-optional-nested-object-variable)

Answer (score 1):

As of Terraform v1.3 the [Optional Object Type Attributes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes) feature is official, which means it is no longer an experiment and the syntax is considered stable.

As mentioned in previous comments, you can now do something like:

```
variable "list_of_users" {
  type = map(object({
    email = string
    group_memberships = optional(string, "")
  }))
}
```

In the above example, using the default value (`""`) allows the Terraform code in the project/module to function as if there is always a value even if it is omitted from the input variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is support for this as a [Terraform "experiment"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/defaults.html) (it's implemented, but could change or be removed in future versions). You have to declare in your module that you're using the experiment:

```
terraform {
  # Optional attributes and the defaults function are
  # both experimental, so we must opt in to the experiment.
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}
```

And then you would use it in your case like this:

```
variable "list_of_users" {
  type = map(object({
    email = string
    group_memberships = optional(string)
  }))
}
```

Now, if `group_membership` isn't defined for a given user, that field will have the value of `null`, so you can now do:

```
resource "user_api_from_provider" "user_generate" {
  ...
  group_memberships = each.value.group_memberships != null ? [user_api_from_provider.group_generate[each.value["group_memberships"]].id] : null
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the experiment, you should be able to do this (untested):

```
resource "user_api_from_provider" "user_generate" {
  ...
  group_memberships = contains(each.value, "group_memberships") ? [user_api_from_provider.group_generate[each.value["group_memberships"]].id] : null
}
```