# Terraform error: string required for empty variables

Tags: terraform

We have a block the following terraform code in our module template:

```
...
%{ for ip in int.ip_addr ~}
    - type: static
      address: ${int.ip}
      netmask: ${int.cidr}
%{ endfor ~}

%{ if length(int.routes) != 0 ~}
      routes:
%{ for dst in int.routes ~}
      - gateway: ${int.routes_to}
        network: ${int.routes_via}
%{ endfor ~}
%{ endif ~}
...
```

in our resources, we define them like this and it is working. However, this requires defining the empty variables.

Is it a default expression in terraform to omit empty variables?

```
  linux_networks  = [
    {
      bridge = "br0"
      device = "eth0"
      vlan = 11
      ips = []
      routes = [ "10.20.230.0/24","10.20.231.64/26" ]
      route_gateway = "10.20.232.1"
    },
    {
      bridge = "br1"
      device  = "eth1"
      ips  = []
      routes = []
      route_gateway = ""
    }
```

Comment: What is the FULL error message showing exact line where the error occurs?

Comment: @Marcin,

This is the line of error:
`The given value is not suitable for child module variable "linux_networks"
defined at ../../modules/generic_linux/variables.tf:64,1-26: element 0:
element "routes": string required.`

Line 64 was pointing to the codeblock for `%{ if length(int.routes) != 0 ~}` , I trimmed it to keep the post short. Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1: `optional` attributes/default values

Since Terraform 1.3 you can define default values for optional attributes in nested variables.

In this example, `linux_networks[*].routes` will be set to an empty list if there is no value given.

```
variable "linux_networks" {
  type = list(object({
    # ... other attributes ...
    routes = optional(list, [])
  }))
  default = []

  # ... other variable attributes ...
}
```

See more in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958521/8078044) and the [related Terraform docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes)

## Method 2: `try` function

If you cannot change the variable definition, you could check for a missing variable at each place the attribute is accessed.

```
%{ if length(try(int.routes, [])) != 0 ~}
```

See [Terraform docs for `try`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try)

Comment: Method 1 is what I am looking for exactly, thank you!!